# how can make MyFirebaseMessaging for 2 app (Driver app and customer app) in one app (driver and customer app)?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm making an app like uber clone app, but in one app in `MyFirebaseMessaging` in uber clone app he has 2 app driver and customer and in his class `MyfirebaseMessaging` he made a different code for driver and customer like this.

For driver app:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {
 @Override
 public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

  LatLng customer_location = new Gson().fromJson(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), LatLng.class);
  Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AppelPassager.class);
  intent.putExtra("lat", customer_location.latitude);
  intent.putExtra("lng", customer_location.longitude);
  intent.putExtra("passager", remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(intent);
 }
}
```

For customer app:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessaging_T extends FirebaseMessagingService {
 @Override
 public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
  if (remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle().equals("Notice")) {
   android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler(getMainLooper());
   handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
     Toast.makeText(MyFirebaseMessaging_T.this, "" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   });

  } else if (remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle().equals("Arrivé")) {
   showArrivedNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
  }
 }

 private void showArrivedNotification(String body) {
  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());
  builder.setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
   .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
   .setContentTitle("Arrivé").setContentText(body).setContentIntent(contentIntent);
  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
 }
}
```

I have one app. How can i post them in one class? Please help me.